# How can u create folder inside the selected path in powerapps gallery to a sharepoint library using Powerapps?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a gallery wherein the data source is connected Documents in sharepoint library. I already create flow that triggered the creation of folder in /Shared Documents path, however want I want after that creation of folder I need to create another folder inside it or another folder inside the folder that I have created.

Can someone help me with this matter. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to achieve this, is to extend your existing flow with another step that uses the path of the new folder to add a child folder (from the outputs of the action creating it). This, however is not very flexible.

[How to create subfolders with Power Automate](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-folder-and-sub-folder-in-sharepoint-library-using-power-automate/)

Alternatively, you can use the Respond to PowerApps action to feed back the path of the new folder to Power Apps. Then you can use the result to trigger the same flow again, with different inputs as many times as you want.

[Responding to Power Apps from Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/return-data-to-powerapps/)

Yet another option is to create this functionality in a solution. This enables you to call your folder-creating flow as a child flow. Then you could create an arbitrary number of parent flows, e.g. one flow calling it from the app, then another flow could fire when the folder is created to add a child folder, etc.

[How to create a parent-child flow relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-child-flows)

You can also look into the SharePoint REST API reference to see if there are any useful additional options when creating folders/subfolders.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it?